# How to kill a process with QProcess::execute()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess, taskkill

I've some problems with killing a process using `taskkill`.

My code:

```
QStringList args;
args << "/F";
args << "/IM testApp.exe";
QProcess::execute("taskkill", args); //Should be 'taskkill /IM testApp.exe /F'
```

Output (translated from german):

```
ERROR: Invalid argument - "/IM testApp.exe".
Type "TASKKILL /?" to show the syntax.
```

Comment: You could also do `QStringList args{"/F","/IM","testApp.exe"};` then `QProcess::execute("taskkill", args);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"/IM testApp.exe" makes a single arg, but should be two args. You get the command `taskkill /F "/IM testApp.exe"`. The proper invocation is

```
QStringList args;
args << "/F";
args << "/IM";
args << "testApp.exe";
QProcess::execute("taskkill", args);
```